# An argument named "networking_mode" is not expected here when creating GKE cluster

Tags: terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

As per this [issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/6744) we need to use `networking_mode="vpc_native"` but I get the following error:

`An argument named "networking_mode" is not expected here.`

Any idea how to make it work?

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "primary" {
  name     = "test"
  network  = "test"
  subnetwork = "private"
  location               = "us-west1-a"
  remove_default_node_pool = true
  initial_node_count = 1
  networking_mode             = "VPC_NATIVE"


  ip_allocation_policy {
    cluster_ipv4_cidr_block  = ""
    services_ipv4_cidr_block = ""
  }

output ommited..
....
```

Comment: It seems that this argument is in `beta`. Verify that you are using `google-beta` terraform provider. You can find more information about this [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/provider_versions).

Comment: As @Styszma mentioned, in Terraform this seems to be in beta as per [this](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_cluster#networking_mode), is this also failing with `google-beta` provider ?